# Put/print mean of a variable to log in SAS

Tags: sas

How do i print the mean of a variable to the log in SAS?

```
data fruit;
input zip fruit & $22. pounds;
datalines;
10034 apples, grapes kiwi  123456
92626  oranges  97654
25414 pears apple      987654
;
```

This is what I've tried:

```
data _null_;
   set fruit;
   put mean(zip);
run;
```

Comment: You cannot use a function in a PUT statement in that way.  Do you have to have it go to the log?  You could just run PROC MEANS.  You will have better luck if you RTM and not expect R syntax to work in SAS.

Comment: If you're transitioning to SAS remember it goes through a data set line by line, so something the mean function works on a single row, not on a column.  R takes the data and considers it a matrix/array/dataframe and you can do matrix math.  That's not how SAS works...one line at a time...but it can handle larger data without issues that way.

Comment: @data_null_  thanks, it does not have to go to the log. It just have to go to my head, using the smallest amount of keystrokes/mouseclicks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PROC SQL.

```
proc sql noprint; 
/*noprint as you don't want to print to the defined output location, just the log*/

/*format, formats the value.  into :<> puts the value into a macro variable named <>*/
select mean(zip) format=best32.
   into :zip_mean
   from fruit;

/*%put writes a message to the log*/
%put Mean of Zip: &zip_mean;
quit;
```

If you are OK writing the value to the open output location then just use:

```
proc sql;
select mean(zip) format=best32.
   from fruit;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [MEANS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#means-overview.htm) procedure to calculate the mean of the pounds variable, followed by a [CALL SYMPUT](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000210266.htm) routine to assign the value to a macro variable, and finally a `%PUT` to print it in the log.

```
proc means data=fruit;
  var pounds;
  output out=testmean mean=fruit_mean;
run;

data _null_;
  set testmean;
  call symput("fruit_avg",fruit_mean);
run;

%put mean of x is &fruit_avg;
```

Answer (score 0):

In data step, you can use `putlog` statement to print the value on log. Based on @cherry_bueno 's answer, the `putlog` version is:

```
proc means data=fruit;
  var pounds;
  output out=testmean mean=fruit_mean;
run;

data _null_;
  set testmean;
  putlog 'mean of x is ' fruit_mean;
run;
```