# SAS Print a value in the log

Tags: sas, console, output

I just want to print the output of a simple operation to the SAS log.

For instance, how can I see the value of `quantile('T', .75, 1000)`? Is there a smarter way to check what does `quantile('T', .75, 1000)` equal to than printing it to the log?

```
%let t_value = quantile('T', .75, 1000); 
%put &t_value.;
```

Others use a proc procedure [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790611/put-print-mean-of-a-variable-to-log-in-sas) but I cannot believe I need to create a data set to check a value...

Comment: SAS doesn't have a 'console' type view similar to other languages and most calculations are done within a data step or proc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the macro function `%SYSFUNC` to invoke non-macro (i.e. DATA step) functions in macro.

Example:

```
%put NOTE: quantile('T', .75, 1000) is %SYSFUNC(quantile(T, .75, 1000));
```

will log

```
11854  %put NOTE: quantile('T', .75, 1000) is %SYSFUNC(quantile(T, .75, 1000));
NOTE: quantile('T', .75, 1000) is 0.67473516460692
```

Tip: Literal arguments you might use in DATA step do not need to be so in `%SYSFUNC` invocations.  Carefully examine `%SYSFUNC(quantile(T, .75, 1000))`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a data set, but another option is a data step with the `_null_` data set.

```
data _null_;
x = quantile('T', 0.75, 1000);
put x; 
run;
```